# Image Picker not opening after asking permission on Android in flutter. [Wokring fine on IOS]

Tags: image, flutter, picker

I am using a Cupertino switch for picking image from gallery. First time when user clicks it ask for permission. After getting the permission the imagePicker never opens the gallery. when i click the button again it shows
Image picker already active. If i close the app and open again it works fine. I have tried:
1. Flutter clean , flutter run
2. Upgrading the dependencies

Nothing works.

here is my code:

```
Widget _rightSectionPhoto() {
return new Container(
  child: CupertinoSwitch(
    value: isSwitchedforidPic,
    onChanged: isSwitchedforidPicStatus
        ? (value) {
            if (value == true) {
              setState(() {
                isSwitchedforidStatus = false;
                getImage();
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                isImageUploaded = false;
              });
            }
          }
        : null,
    activeColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  ),
);
```

}

And here is getImage function

```
 Future getImage() async {
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
  imageQuality: 10,
);

if (image == null) {
  setState(() {
    isSwitchedforidPic = false;
    isSwitchedforidStatus = true;
    isImageUploaded = false;
  });
} else {
  List<int> imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
  base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
  setState(() {
    isImageUploaded = true;
  });
}
```

}